# Proof permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, permutation-matrices

For every permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ we define a $n \times n$ matrix $$P_\sigma:=(\delta_i,\sigma_j)_{1\le i,j\le n}$$

Show that the matrix $P_\sigma$ is a permutation matrix and for every permutation matrix $P$ there is only one permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $P=P_\sigma$.

I don't really get the notation here, could someone quickly clear that up.

I mean i know that $\sigma$ is bijective meaning $\sigma: \{1,2,3,4,.....,n\} \rightarrow \{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3,\sigma_4,.....,\sigma_n\}$ But in this case for $P_\sigma$ to be a permutation matrix, don't i have to use Kronecker Delta to to define if $\delta_i=\sigma_j$ then we have 1, otherwise 0, for
$P_\sigma$ to be a permutation matrix...But from the question i get the feeling i dont need to do this or rather i'm not allowed to do this. So i thought maybe that notation means something else than i thought.

Comment: "Show that the matrix Pσ is a permutation matrix " ==> what is your defintion of a permutation matrix ? Some people would take your definition of Pσ as wht is means to be a permutation matrix

Comment: ehmm the normal definition? in every row and column there is only 1 (1), otherwise 0? Well at least  i assumed so....

Comment: OK. Then it seems to me that your bijectivity argument proves that $P_\sigma$ is a permutation matrix ! In order to prove the converse, how can you retrieve $\sigma$ from a given $P$ ? (Hint : compute $P \cdot \delta_i$)

Comment: oh that was right, $P\times \delta_i$ would give us $\sigma$....And the only way that works is that if P is a permutation matrix

Comment: I guess what confused me was i didn't want to look at a set of numbers of permutations as matrix...But then still, i dont understand that notation of $P_\sigma$ and i dont know how to go about the proof...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation $$(\delta_i,\sigma_j)$$ should be interpreted as the value of Dirac $\delta_i$ acting on $\sigma_j$ (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3453834)), i.e.,

$$\delta_i(\sigma_j)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if} \ \sigma_j=i \iff \sigma(j)=i\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

giving indeed exactly one "$1$" on every line.

For your second part: on inspection of a permutation matrix, which is known to have one "1" per line and per column (it is their definition), on each line "i", there is a unique "one" situated on a certain column $j$ determines the image $\sigma(j)=i$. When all lines have been processed, $\sigma$ is fully determined. But $\sigma$ has to be proven injective. This is where the other unicity intervenes: no chance that $\sigma(j_1)=\sigma(j_2)$ for $j_1 \ne j_2$ because there is a unique "one" **per column**.

The result is indeed the classical permutation matrix associated to $\sigma$...

**Remark:** notation $(u,v)$ is indeed puzzling ; it is usually used for dot products, but sometimes as well for the "action" of the first argument onto the second: $(f,x):=f(x)$, mainly in the context of duality (like in the reference I gave above).

Comment: speaking of which, i guess i have a guess, The topic is on determinant, $\delta_i,\sigma_j$ are interchangeable pairs. If the permutation is odd, its -1, if its even then its 1. Allthou i dont know if its related to this question....to be honest i read the text on this permutation thing for 5 times now (linear algebra by kunze) and i still havnt completely understood....

Comment: I just added a reference for the notation. Consider Dirac $\delta_a$ as a black box reacting when one submits it a value $v$ by emitting a $1$ when $v=a$ and a zero otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! Now you answer basically gave me part a)   for part b) ill just need to mention that sigma is bijective, therefore injective so if $\sigma(a)=\sigma(b) \rightarrow a=b$ therefore, if $P=P_\sigma$ then $\sigma$  is uniquely defined . Would that be enough?

Comment: 1) I just corrected an error : it is $\sigma(j)=i$ not $\sigma(i)=j$ of course. 2) I wouldn't give the explanation $\sigma(a)=\sigma(b) \implies a=b$ because in this way you don't refer to the matrices. I would advise you to write sentences like that : on inspection of a permutation matrix, which is known to have one "1" per line and per column (it is their definition), on each line "$i$", the column $j$ containing the "one" determines the image $\sigma(j)=i$ that, at the end when all the lines have been browsed determine in a unique way $\sigma$. [continued]

Comment: [continuation] **But** $\sigma$ could be non injective. This is where the other unicity intervenes: no risk that an image is taken twice because there is one "one" per column....